# Rendering nested Collection with meteor js template

Tags: javascript, html, json, templates, meteor

I am new to JavaScript and Meteor. I managed to set up all server side communication but can't figure out how to render a block of data within my Collection. This is it:

```
{"NAME1":{"service":"NAME1","count":0,"maxCount":0},"NAME2":{"service":"NAME2","count":1,"maxCount":1},"NAME3":{"service":"NAME3","count":2,"maxCount":2},"NAME4":{"service":"NAME4","count":3,"maxCount":3},"NAME5":{"service":"NAME5","count":4,"maxCount":4},"NAME6":{"service":"NAME6","count":5,"maxCount":5}}
```

I am able to extract this block by calling the tag name. After that, i am stuck. Each NAME as a key is a dynamic string, i only know that values are array of - service, count, and maxCount and i want these values to display in table format with 3 columns - name, count, and max. I probably should use a cursor for this block rendering but can't figure out how to do it. Please help.

JSON block that i want to render is within "p" tags

```
<template name="template_name">
<h2> Data </h2>
   {{#each all_blocks}}
     {{#with block_i_need }}
        <p>"block i need: " {{.}}</p>
      {{/with}}
    {{/each}}
</template>`
```

How do i pass block_i_need to a function and return service, count, and maxCount values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.values` to extract an array of values of an object.

```js
Template.whatever.services = function() {
  var object = getThatJsonBlockSomehow();
  // object is {"NAME1":{"service":"NAME1","count":0,"maxCount":0}, ...};
  return _.values(object);
  // returns [{"service":"NAME1","count":0,"maxCount":0}, ...]
}
```

Then, in the template, you can use a `#each` to iterate over that array. (`#each` allows you to iterate through arrays or cursors.)

```html
<template name="whatever">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Service</th><th>Count</th><th>Max count</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- iterate over the [{"service":"NAME1","count":0,"maxCount":0}, ...] array -->
    {{#each services}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{service}}</td><td>{{count}}</td><td>{{maxCount}}</td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I guess my javascript is really bad :( I am stuck again on getting this json block out of my collection. See my Edit above. Will greatly appreciate help.

Comment: So, i am passing the right json block to _.value() and getting error "Exception in queue tasks" and nothing is displayed. It seems that i pass the whole block to that value instead of just "NAME1":{"service":"NAME1","count":0,"maxCount":0}. I guess i need to further break down this json block.